# How to cleanup the user settings file on uninstall?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, application-settings

When using `Settings.settings` when an user changes a setting it saves it to:

> %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\%ProcessName%_Url_%hashCode%\%version%\user.config

For an InnoSetup uninstaller it is very difficult to clean all those files.

Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to change where the ms config stuff writes settings, but after researching it, I ended up just avoiding the MS settings stuff (except for the app.exe.config file that's in the same folder as the exe itself) and just used XML serialization to serialize\deserialize my own settings object into an appropriate \AppData\Folder.

Comment: Keep in mind that while you +could+ save settings into the same folder as the app (and many apps do, for the purpose of being "movable" on, say, a memstick), most apps don't because typical users won't have write rights to the \program Files\* folder.

Comment: it would be nice if you could point me how to change that folder

Comment: Well, in VB, you might use         

    _FileName = "MyAppName\Settings.config"
    _FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), _FileName)

This would construct a filename pointing to the common APPDATA folder (under XP, that is typically C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data)

That "SpecialFolder" enumeration has all the typical "system known" folder locations. Generally, your safe to read/write into the current user's profile AND to the ALL USERS profile, but definitely NOT to the PROGRAM FILES folder.